# use mat-datepicker directly without input

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to put the datepicker in a permanent sidebar always visible and not dependent on an input, is this possible?
I imagined that just putting the component and adding opened = true could leave the datepicker inside a box always visible.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 39, accepted):

turns out this is pretty straightforward import the MatDatePickerModule as per usual and then simply use the mat-calendar selector

```
<mat-calendar></mat-calendar>
```

In order to hook into the selection via typescript

```
  @ViewChild(MatCalendar) _datePicker: MatCalendar<Date>

ngOnInit() {
    this._datePicker.selectedChange.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can also do `<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="selectedDate = $event">
</mat-calendar>` - which avoids the viewchild and also enables the calendar to show the selected date

Comment: I agree with @JonasPraem - currently just rendering `<mat-calendar></mat-calendar>` will always use today's date

Comment: `readonly selectedChanged: EventEmitter<D>;`
* @deprecated Switch to the `dateChange` and `dateInput` binding on the input element.
 * @deletion-target 6.0.0

Comment: Now should be `"selectedDate = $event.value"`

Comment: Wow...  <mat-calendar> is awesome... much neater than the full-block Angular Materials DatePicker.  But why is it not documented anywhere ?

Comment: Just to say, the Calendar component fits in really nicely in as a date picker for an agGrid cell.  It's much more stylish than the full-blown Materials date picker.   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5266363/agGrid-for-Angular-the-missing-manual

Comment: Just a heads up. For Material version 8 i had to import MatDatepickerModule (so P in picker is lowercase)

Answer (score 25):

You can also try to hide with css ex:

```
<mat-form-field style="width:1px;visibility:hidden;">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" >
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-button (click)="picker.open()" ></button>
```

The advantage of hiding with css is that the datepicker is positioned relative to the hidden form-field

Comment: i set [hidden]="true" but it not work. and base your answer i use style="visibility:hidden;" and it completely disappear. thanks Stefan ;)

Comment: I had to add these modules in the import section of my module too:
`MatFormFieldModule`, `MatInputModule`

Comment: How to get the icon visible, otherwise this is working solution.

Answer (score -1):

The only working way I found is large and borrrrrrrring but works:

([partial credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520660/2118777))

### Html

```
  <mat-form-field id="dashboardComponent">
    <input matInput
      [matDatepicker]="matDatepicker"
      [formControl]="dateFormControl"
      (dateChange)="onDateChanged('change', $event)"
      [max]="datePickerMaxDate"
      >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="matDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #matDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

### component.ts

```
@Component({
    ....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class MyComponent {

    // Date Picker
    public currentDate: Date = new Date() // set default here
    public dateFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl(this.currentDate)
```

### css

```
/* DATE PICKER */
mat-form-field {
    margin: 0 0.5em; //adapt me to your needs
    width: 0.8em; //adapt me to your needs
    font-weight: normal;
}


#dashboardComponent {
    .mat-form-field-underline {
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```