# How to remove underline of mat-select component

Tags: angular-material

I am using basic mat-select component in my project.

```
 <mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

how can i remove the underline,I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45556972/how-to-hide-delete-underline-input-angular-material?rq=1) too still no result.

Comment: [The answer by David Rinck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520660/2100126) on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48540533/styling-mat-form-field-input-in-angular-material) (not marked as the right answer) is better approach I think. *"...use an ID, which allows you a higher specificity...and put the style on global styles file".* You can refers to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520660/2100126) of [David Rinck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308962/david-rinck).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kw2psd?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.css)

[image]

Comment: Can i apply it only for one `mat-select `?, I have many `mat-select ` in the form.

Comment: it is effecting to all mat-form-fields

Comment: this also worked for my form where I have `<mat-form-field>` and inside I have an input div `<input matInput type="text">`

Answer (score 30):

You can also use the `appearance` property on the `<form-field>` . Setting `appearance="none"` will remove the underline without any css hack. And you can also get rid of `::ng-deep` which is not recommended.

So your code will be like this.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="none">
 <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

For more information on appearance, you can check here. https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants

Comment: There is nothing about appearance "none" in the material docs for some reason.  I confirmed it does work though.

Comment: `error TS2322: Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.`

Comment: appearance='none worked for the legacy components. IT does not work for mdc. Anybody know how to get rid of it for mdc?

Answer (score 3):

For legacy material components set  appearance to none:

```
<mat-form-field appearance='none'>
```

For mdc components:

```
.mdc-line-ripple {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`::ng-deep` is going to be depracated.

Use css hierarchy.  If you have a global css or scss file... then in the component, wrap this in a div and give it a class.

For example,

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">

...all your html code here

</div>
```

Then, in your global css/scss file, you can target the `.mat-form-field-underline` class like so:

```css
.content-wrapper .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Here, notice that we don't use comma after class names.  This is using hierarchy.  It saying that we only want to target the native `.mat-form-field-underline` class that is wrapped inside the `.content-wrapper`

Hope this helps.  Glad my senior developer had shared me this as we used ViewEncapsualtion, which bled css all over the place.  This is the right solution to our use case, hope it helps yours.

This also works for other native mat classes for customization of your code/html.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the hierarchy and not using `::ng-deep`. Sadly I tried and it didn't work for my particular case. I even copied the selector straight out of Chrome Inspector, but if I didn't put `::ng-deep` it wouldn't apply the style.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide underline in particular input only then you can do something like below.

```
   <div class="select-block">
        <mat-form-field>
           <mat-select placeholder="Select Option">
             <mat-option>One</mat-option>
             <mat-option>Two</mat-option>
             <mat-option>Three</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

- Add the below-mentioned line of code in the parent class of mat-form-field.

> ```
> .select-block{
>     /deep/ mat-form-field {
>       &.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
>         .mat-form-field-underline {
>           display: none;
>         }
>       }
>     }
>  }
> ```

Try this way to hide the underline.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two options to solve the problem:

1. You can directly setup `appearance="none"` in `mat-form-field` tag 
   ex. `<mat-form-field appearance="none">`.
2. You can hide using css 
   ex. `::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

I had appearance="fill" on the mat-form-field. These settings worked to remove the underline for me:

scss:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill {
  .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Add set encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.None in the component:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```