# Style input material angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

On the angular material and the input component (matInput) how can I modify the style of all inputs in typescript?

I'm trying this way, but it only modifies the first element.

```
ngAfterViewInit () {
    const matlabel = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector ('.mat-form-field-label');
    matlabel.style.color = 'white';
  }
```

=====================

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
      <table cellspacing="0" class="tb-login">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field class="form-login">
              <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Login" formControlName="login"  class="input-login"/>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field  class="form-login">
              <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"   class="input-login"/>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn_login">Login</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Angular v7
Material Angular v7

I will be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: For change the styles of material inputs with css => https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409733/2736742

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`Renderer2`**](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setStyle) along with [**`ViewChild`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to do this.

`Renderer2` gives Platform Agnostic APIs to modify the DOM and should be used as opposed to the native `document` APIs.

You can inject `Renderer2` as a dependency in your Component and then call the `setStyle` method on it passing the element you want to set the style on, name of the style(`'background'`) and the value of it(`red` in my eg).

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({...})
export class InputOverviewExample {

  @ViewChild('food') matInput: MatInput;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.matInput.nativeElement, 'background', 'red');
  }

}
```

And in your Template, create template variable(s) like I've done on the `input` tag with the name `food`. This is what I'm using in `@ViewChild('food')`:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #food matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/change-matinput-style-in-ts?file=app/input-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Very good! In this example I have two fields / inputs do I need to reference for each one? Example # field1 and # field2 or is there a way to apply the style to all of the html inputs in question?

Comment: I actually tried using `MatInput` but apparently doesn't work that way as accessing it via `ViewChild` returns `undefined`. So yeah, if you have two fields, then you'll have to do it this way only by defining two properties on your Component Class.

Comment: OK! This way I saw that I can change the color of the background, but could you tell me how to change the color of the label and input line?